# Почему перестал работать ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Раньше, при сохранении файла 123.txt, запись выводилась на экран без перезагрузки.
Сейчас не работает в Google Chrome

Как ajax сделать кроссбраузерно?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>

        <script>
            var auto_refresh = setInterval(
            function() {
                $('#load_div').fadeOut('slow').load('123.txt').fadeIn("slow");
            }, 3000);
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="load_div">111</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Тоесть *Раньше не работал в Google Chrome, но сейчас работает*?

Comment: А Лиса это Firefox, в ней тоже самое или работает?

Comment: И правда, запрос срабатывает, но текст не меняется. Скорее всего кеширование

Comment: Через `$.ajax` с `cache: false`. Как коротко это в `load` сделать мне не известно. Ответ написал ниже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup ({cache: false});
    $('#load_div').fadeOut('slow').load('123.txt').fadeIn("slow");
}, 3000);
```

---

Для html файла есть такой вариант

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="load_div">111</div>
        <input type='file'>
    </body>
 
    <script>
        input = document.querySelector('input');
        input.onchange = function() {
            f = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
            auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
                // $.ajaxSetup ({cache: false});
                $('#load_div').fadeOut('slow').load(f).fadeIn("slow");
            }, 3000);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Странно, а у меня заработало

Comment: @LenovoID, как насчёт этого варианта? `load('123.txt?_=0')`

Comment: @LenovoID, кстати хром ещё хорошо скрипты кеширует. Так что надо попробовать в режиме инкогнито запустить

Comment: @LenovoID, ёкарный бабай, линкусоид чтоли?) Там клиент, скорее всего, другой. Ещё и с рабочего стола

Comment: @LenovoID, переименовал php докумас в html страничку, открыл и не обновляет ничего, а потому что путь до 123.txt другой или нет доступа через браузер к файлу. Открой консолечку и погляди

Comment: @LenovoID, уот так уот *XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/server/www/t4/123.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.*

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41719/discussion-between-lenovoid-and-doofy).

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего, вступает в силу кеширование:

> It is roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success)

Отсюда: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Параметризируйте ваш запрос, чтобы браузер каждый раз получал "свежую" версию файла:

```
$('#load_div').fadeOut('slow').load('123.txt?id={id}').fadeIn("slow");
```

Как сгенерировать уникальный идентификатор можете посмотреть здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231459/create-unique-id-with-javascript

Comment: Да и лучше, чтобы анимация была при изменении файла. У меня Opera, всё работает

Comment: doofy глянь через Хром - плиз

Comment: @LenovoID, хрома нет, но вы держитесь там, всего Вам доброго, хорошего настроения и здоровья. А в Опере 38 всё работает